# Image Conversion library: Word, PDF, Excel to Images

Tags: image, image-processing

We have a requirement to convert any incoming documents which are either in Excel, PDF and Word to images. Any recommendation?

I am NOT sure whether ImageMagik would do this but my understanding it is ONLY for format conversion of images and I guess handles PDF as well. What about Excel and Word?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You could convert everything to pdf first using:

`$ libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf *.`**libreofficeextension**

and then use imagemagick...

you might have some formatting issues in word and especially in powerpoint

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a gui instance of libreoffice running.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct -- imagemagick **won't** handle the MS Office formats because it only handles image format conversion.

For PDFs, can just use imagemagick directly:

```
convert -density 400 filename.pdf filename.jpeg
```

It will give you files:

- filename[0].jpg
- filename[2].jpg
- ...
- filename[N-1].jpg

Where N was the number of pages in your document.  `pdf2ps` will achieve the same thing, but you'll need to play around with the command-line parameters to get the same output quality.

For the MS Office products, I remember that there is some sort of API that allows you access to the suite's features (this was MS Office 2007, from memory), like opening a file and exporting it to PDF.  If you can get things out to PDF, then you can use the method above to convert it to images.  Some negative points:

- This was many years ago at my previous job, and I can't remember what exactly it was called or how to use it.
- I remember the output PDF formatting wasn't great (not 100% like it appears on the screen) but it readable.  This may have improved since I last used it.
- I have a vague recollection of it firing up an Excel window in the background, so it's not entirely a command-line solution (may be unsuitable for servers)

Comment: I know it is possible to do this MS-Office conversion ti images but I am still researching a way. We need to do this conversion of MS-office docs to images almost on the fly so the need of APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question still this is how I solved:

1. use Windows machine
2. Install MS Office suit
3. Use https://officetopdf.codeplex.com/ for converting any office format to PDF
4. Use Imagemagick for pdf to image format.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Is not me… I am just making [**reviews**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) as many others