# PPT to PDF converter in UNIX

Tags: unix, pdf, powerpoint, converters

I am trying to convert a ppt file to a pdf file in command line. I have tried unoconv but it screws up the layout. Is there any open source utility that is able to this without messing around with the layout?

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729337/image-conversion-library-word-pdf-excel-to-images) -- it doesn't have any suitable solutions yet, but covers common ground.

You should keep in mind that PPT is a proprietary format.  Even OpenOffice, a fully functional open-source office suite, has problems with formatting & laying out PPT files sometimes.  This is even before handling things like animations, etc.  Your best bet is probably to use a Windows machine (argh) with MS Office (argh) for the PDF export.